# How to programmatically pass input to Java keytool?

Tags: java, ssl, keytool, jcabi

I'm trying to fix a problem in the open-source project [jcabi-ssl-maven-plugin](https://github.com/jcabi/jcabi-ssl-maven-plugin).

The problem occurs in the method `com.jcabi.ssl.maven.plugin.Keytool#genkey`:

```
@Loggable(Loggable.DEBUG)
public void genkey() throws IOException {
    final Process proc = this.proc(
        "-genkeypair",
        "-alias",
        "localhost",
        "-keyalg",
        "RSA",
        "-keysize",
        "2048",
        "-keypass",
        this.password
    ).start(); // Here we launch the keytool
    final PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream())
    );
    writer.print("localhost\n"); // These and other writer.print(...) statements 
    writer.print("ACME Co.\n"); // write answers to questions of keytool
    writer.print("software developers\n");
    writer.print("San Francisco\n");
    writer.print("California\n");
    writer.print("US\n");
    writer.print("yes\n");
    writer.close();
    new VerboseProcess(proc).stdout();
    Logger.info(
        this,
        "Keystore created in '%s' (%s)",
        this.keystore,
        FileUtils.byteCountToDisplaySize(this.keystore.length())
    );
}
```

The purpose of this code is to

1. launch the Java keytool program and
2. answer its questions on the command line.

First step involves programmatic call like `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\bin\keytool" -genkeypair -alias localhost -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keypass some-password -storetype jks -noprompt -storepass some-password -keystore C:\Users\DP118M\AppData\Local\Temp\junit4133348108660376680\keystore.jks`.

Then, keytool asks you several questions (see below, translated from German):

```
What is your name?
  [Unknown]:  A
What is the name of your organizational unit?
  [Unknown]:  A
What is the name of your organisation?
  [Unknown]:  A
What is the name of your city or county?
  [Unknown]:  A
What is the name of your state?
  [Unknown]:  A
What is the country code of your organizational unit?
  [Unknown]:  A
Is CN=A, OU=A, O=A, L=A, ST=A, C=A correct?
  [No]:  Yes
```

Instead of typing in the answers (`A` above) manually, the code above uses `writer.print(...);` statements.

But they obviously don't work because when I run a test, which involves the use of keytool (e. g. [com.jcabi.ssl.maven.plugin.CacertsTest#importsCertificatesFromKeystore](https://github.com/jcabi/jcabi-ssl-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/test/java/com/jcabi/ssl/maven/plugin/CacertsTest.java)), I get following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Non-zero exit code 1: Keytool Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Too many repeated attempts. Program will be terminated.
\n
    at com.jcabi.log.VerboseProcess.stdout(VerboseProcess.java:220)
    at com.jcabi.log.VerboseProcess.stdout(VerboseProcess.java:158)
    at com.jcabi.ssl.maven.plugin.Keytool.genkey(Keytool.java:116)
    at com.jcabi.ssl.maven.plugin.Keystore.activate(Keystore.java:121)
    at com.jcabi.ssl.maven.plugin.CacertsTest.importsCertificatesFromKeystore(CacertsTest.java:64)
```

I assume that the root cause of this problem is that the `writer.print(...);` statements fail to deliver their texts to the keytool.

How can I fix this (make sure that in the `com.jcabi.ssl.maven.plugin.Keytool#genkey` method the messages written by `writer.print(...);` are correctly delivered to `keytool`) ?

**Update 1 (28.12.2014 MSK):**

I think I found the cause. I'm running my test on Windows, so calls like `writer.print("localhost\n");` need to be replaced by `writer.print("localhost" + System.getProperty("line.separator"));`.

This is easy.

But there is another part. The developers of this code obviously worked on an English speaking version of keytool, so at the end it expects a `yes` (see last question in the example output keytool above).

Therefore there is the statement

```
writer.print("yes\n");
```

But I'm using a German Windows version, so in my case the correct response is not `yes`, but `Ja`.

If I change the code like this, it works (the test does not fail):

```
final String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
writer.print("localhost" + newLine);
writer.print("ACME Co." + newLine);
writer.print("software developers" + newLine);
writer.print("San Francisco" + newLine);
writer.print("California" + newLine);
writer.print("US" + newLine);
writer.print("Ja" + newLine);
```

I appreciate hints, on how I can make this part of code work on operating systems with any language (how can I avoid hardcoding `yes` and `Ja`).

Comment: (1) If you pass the subject-name fields as an argument using `-dname` -- note that's several fields combined into one argument like `CN=localhost, O=ACME Co., etc` -- it doesn't ask the "all correct?" question. See the `keytool` doc. (2) But you didn't specify `-storepass` so (either way) `keytool` should prompt for that and you aren't answering that prompt, so it shouldn't work now. See the `keytool` doc.

Comment: can you use `KeyStore` class of java instead ? something like this http://goo.gl/yB2ICk , this would be much simpler